# Displaying MediaStream with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, webrtc

I'm working with media streams - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream.

I'm trying the following:

```
<video data-bind="attr: {src: displayedDeviceSession().stream()}"></video>
```

However the video doesn't get displayed.  I see this:

```
<video data-bind="attr: {src: displayedDeviceSession().stream()}" src="[object MediaStream]"></video>
```

I've also tried the `srcObject` attribute to no avail (  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject ).  Is it possible to leverage knockout to display dynamic media streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use computeds to display the video streams

```
 <video id="displayedDeviceSessionVideo"></video>
```

This is added to your model where the stream property is:

```
self.stream = ko.observable();

self.streamWatch = ko.computed(function () {
    var video = document.getElementById("displayedDeviceSessionVideo");
    if (self.stream() != null) {
        // Start Stream
        video.srcObject = self.stream();

    } else {
       // Stop
    }
}, self);
```

I believe what you are doing is correct but to complex do be done inline html, therefore use the power of knockout in the js model itself.

If video not rendered originally then why not use `<video onloadstart="loadStream()">`

```
function loadStream() {
    var video = document.getElementById("displayedDeviceSessionVideo");
    if (viewModel.stream() != null) {
        // Start Stream
        video.srcObject = viewModel.stream();

    } else {
       // Stop
    }
}
```

The loadstart event occurs when the browser starts looking for the specified audio/video. This is when the loading process starts.

Refactor code so its in one place and computed will still update stream if changed.

Haven't tested this but in theory this should also work and therefore all knockout:

```
 <video data-bind="event: { onloadstart: loadStream }">
```

Model:

```
self.stream = ko.observable();

self.loadStream = function () {
    var video = document.getElementById("displayedDeviceSessionVideo");
    if (self.stream() != null) {
        // Start Stream
        video.srcObject = self.stream();
     } else {
       // Stop
     }
}

self.streamWatch = ko.computed(function () {
    var stream = self.stream();
    self.loadStream();
}, self);
```

Comment: The only thing that worries me about this approach is if the video element isn't visible at the time of the stream update.  I'd hope there's some way to bind on the element to avoid this... is a custom binding needed here?

Comment: Funny you write this, I had an extra bit at end which said, this is dependant on element being there etc. You can put extra logic, ie. stream.valueHasMutated(). But you would only need this if you dynamically add the video element or its wrapped in knockout `ifs`?

Comment: Yeah - I have template loading that dynamically renders the html that contains my `video` elements.  Tying `hasMutated` to all of my observables and introducing that into my templating logic is a solution, but not one I'm thrilled about (maintenance, readability, elegance, etc).

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't be thrilled about that either, see edit.

Comment: For some reason onloadstart isn't triggering

Comment: I ended up using `data-bind="template: {afterRender: loadStream}"`